# Couch co-op individual loot unbalanced?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

My girlfriend and I only play in offline couch co-op mode. I play a Barb currently at L67 and she plays a Wizard at L69. We're playing ROS on Xbox360.

What we've noticed is that often a chest or treasure goblin or even a low-level boss (champion?) will spit out a lot of loot that goes only to me (that is, it's designated as mine and goes to my character, no matter who picks it up). I'm almost always player 1, but last night, we set her as player 1 thinking that might make a difference, but it didn't.

This happens easily >50% of the time - I get all, she gets bupkus. There's been very few times where SHE got all of the loot, with the remainder more or less evenly distributed between us. It's not just rare or legendary loot - we've seen loot piles that ended up being almost all gems that still all went to me.

Since we've eliminated the possibility that everything is going to Player 1, is it possible that I'm getting all of the loot because my level trails hers a bit? What other factors would contribute to this?

Comment: Do you have more magic-find or gold-find?  If not, it's probably just bad luck combined with confirmation bias.

Comment: I'll check those tonight, as well as actually keeping an account of how often this happens. But my understanding was that MF was so nerfed in ROS that it's basically meaningless anymore and that GF was only for, well, gold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From pure speculation and observation, I think that the game does favor the weaker character in a group as far as loot goes.

However, being below 70 means that not too much time has been spent doing anything that would yield large amounts of loot (and if it is your first time killing certain bosses you will get legendaries while she gets the short end of the stick). Once you are both 70 and have completed the same content or are in adventure mode it will even out a lot more.

Comment: Thanks, Travis - I think you're correct. When we started last night it turned out that she was like 69.9 and I was closer than I thought, like 69.1 (yes, I'm estimating the fractional part for illustrative purposes only). She hit L70 right away and I was only a few minutes behind her. We're in adventure mode and have never played separately so we've seen the same content. Once we both were 70 we didn't see any imbalance in distribution over the 2 rifts and 15 bounties we played last night.

Comment: @kaufman - Good to hear! Now that you are 70, I would suggest going for that Royal Ring of Grandeur :) Best way to do it is to setup a spec that allows you to move as fast as possible, put the difficulty on normal (still drops on normal), and do the act 1 bounties on adventure mode. The cache has a chance to drop the ring. Repeat until you get one, they are best in slot and it is pretty easy to get :) Might take 15-20 tries.

Comment: +1 I hauled my brother's fresh character through T1 rifts to level him up once. In eight rifts, he got all but one legendary drop (30-40 total). Once up to level 70 with me, it evened out.